# Convert pseudo code to Python

Tags: python

Just to be fully up front, this is regarding a homework, but this in itself is not the assignment. The assignment is using noise to create cool graphics. I have a bit of experience in Python but not enough to figure this simple thing out.

I'm having trouble generating a seeded-random [-1,1]. The pseudocode my teacher gave me is from [Hugo Elias.](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm)

Pseudocode:

```
function Noise1(integer x, integer y)
    n = x + y * 57
    n = (n<<13) ^ n;
    return ( 1.0 - ( (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);    
  end function
```

My attempt in Python:

```
def noise(x, y):
    n = x + y * 57
    n = (n<<5) ^ n;
    return ( 1.0 - ( (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0)
```

The problem is the `& 7fffffff` bit in return statement. First, I'm not sure what that operation is. Maybe a bit-shift? Second, I'm not sure how to do that operation in Python. I had just removed that part, but I am getting huge negative numbers, nowhere near a [-1,1]

Comment: Is the ^ exponent or XOR in the pseudocode, I can't tell

Comment: the & is a bit mask (binary AND), and will work in python as is.

Comment: @JesusRamos, my best guess is exponent.

Comment: @Serdalis, how about the `& 7fffffff` ? How do I do that in Python?

Comment: `&` is usually a bitwise AND function, which in this case would mask your resulting number with a 31-bit number (all ones)

Comment: @jb I think it would be safer to assume bitwise XOR since they are using other bitwise operations in the code and would be careful not to use a bitwise symbol for a non-bitwise context.
`& 0x7FFFFFFF` in python

Comment: Yeah I'm just trying to make sure because other than that I see no mistakes...

Comment: I'm not sure about the other numbers, but the `7fffffff` is in hexidecimal, so under Python you need to write it as `0x7fffffff` so Python knows to interpret it correctly. You can also use '0b' for binary under later python versions.

Comment: Thank you all. One step closer to a working program. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` symbol stands for bitwise `AND`
The `^` symbol stands for bitwise `XOR`

and the `7FFFFFFF` is a `HEX` number.
In programming you can represent a hex number using `0x` where `7FFFFFFF` is `0x7FFFFFFF`
[Some further reading on hex numbers](http://www.the-eggman.com/seminars/about_hex.html).

To do a binary `AND` in python you just use `& 0x7FFFFFFF`
see more here about [bitwise operations in python](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `7FFFFFFF` with `0x7FFFFFFF` in your existing code and tried plugging in some random values and all the answers which I got were in [-1, 1].

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is the & 7fffffff bit in return statement. First, I'm not sure what that operation is. Maybe a bit-shift?

A bit mask. `<<` is used for shifting. `&` is bitwise-AND. `7fffffff`, interpreted as a hexadecimal number, is a quantity that, if re-written in binary, has 31 bits, all of which are 1. The effect is to select the low-order 31 bits of the value.

To tell Python that `7fffffff` should be interpreted as a hexadecimal number, you must prefix it with `0x`, hence `0x7fffffff`.

> Second, I'm not sure how to do that operation in Python.

The same way as in the pseudocode (i.e. with `&`).